# Run a Virtual Machine from Virtualbox without launching virtualbox

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine

since you're able to close the Virtualbox window after booting the virtualmachine, I was wondering:

**Is there a way (command or shortcut) to run a VM installed in Virtualbox without having to open and go through Virtualbox's main window in the process?**

I know that the VM is still running from virtualbox, I just wanted to skip this step and go directly to booting the VM in one double-click.

Running windows 7, latest version of virtualbox.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [VBoxManage](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#vboxmanage), in particular the [startvm](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#vboxmanage-startvm) command.

Answer (score 0):

In gnome-do (something similar to launchy/executor/autohotkey, but for linux.), there is a plugin through which you just need to specify the vm name and it provides you with various options (start/stop etc). So, the way to start a vm would be

1. alt+space (my shortcut for gnome-do)
2. type winxp (my vm name)
3. various options come as to what you want to do, when you hit tab. Just select start (usually the default value).

You might be able to set up something similar on windows.